# A question related to UITabelViewCell

Tags: iphone

How to set background image of UITabelViewCell?
I want to set image of each cell of UITabelview
kindly help in this issue aeap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make custom cell by adding image view background to cell. Set image in imageview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create class CustomTabelViewCell and set image in certain custom connected cell!